# UI Bootstrap: Execute specific function before tab changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

As in the title writes, is it possible to intercept tab change event and execute some function before that occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, just add an `ng-click` on the `uib-tab` directive

Here's a demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kvUDpXdVm6IQpR9tD3jJ?p=preview) (note how the code runs before the view changes).

Comment: I have thought of that solution but haven't dared to try, thanks! I was thinking whether is there some better way instead of putting `ng-click` directive on the every tab? I think that this wouldn't be possible to do if I'm adding new tabs later i.e. dynamically?

Comment: if you'll add them dynamically, you'll probably use something like `ng-repeat`, and that will just recopy the same template with the `ng-click`, if you'll want something more "robust" you can use promises (i.e. cancel event if the promise rejects..)

Comment: I have one more question: Why do I have to include `$event` in the function if it's not used?

Comment: you don't really need, i've added it but didn't used it, basically it's the event object, you can modify, and event cancel it